# Bounded Combobox consraint value error when inserting

Tags: c#, sql-server, combobox

I have binded 3 comboboxes separately to 3 different tables. Whenever i select value for metroComboBox2, it gives me this error  "Column 'Cor_ID' is constrained to be unique.  Value '103' is already present." I don't why this error is coming. What is the cause for this error?

```
con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        con.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        String query = "Insert into Teacher (ID,Name,FName,Age,Qualification,Dep_ID,Cor_ID,Sem_ID,Password) VALUES(@ID,@Name,@FName,@Age,@Qualification,@Dep_ID,@Cor_ID,@Sem_ID,@Password)";

        cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);


        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", metroTextBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", metroTextBox2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", metroTextBox3.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", metroTextBox4.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qualification", metroTextBox5.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dep_ID", metroComboBox1.GetItemText(metroComboBox1.SelectedItem));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cor_ID", metroComboBox2.GetItemText(metroComboBox2.SelectedItem));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sem_ID", metroComboBox3.GetItemText(metroComboBox3.SelectedItem));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", metroTextBox7.Text);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Record Inserted");
}
```

Comment: Is there a `Unique Constraint` on the `Teacher` table for that column?

Comment: No i haven't added any such kind of option for that table. I created that table using ERD and not from query.

Comment: Why are you putting all of your metroComboBox1 values into the 3 different ID fields. I thought you had 3 different combo boxes?

Comment: Why are you creating a DataTable then ignoring it?

Comment: First combobox is bound with Department table. Second Combo box is bound with Course table and 3rd with Semester table. And i have made a foreign key with teacher table and then i am inserting record for teacher.

Comment: But your code says different. All of them have `metroComboBox1`.

Comment: Forget Datatable it's of no use here. I will just remove it from code.

Comment: The constrainst error is still there. I just didn't update it sorry for that. Now i have edited it.

Comment: Well, the error is telling you, you do have a constraint on that table.

Comment: How can i remove that constraint? I am a beginner so please tell me.